# Soap web service not getting published for Custom Object return type in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing a soap web service. I have a method which should returns a custom object ResultDto. When I add it as a return type to my method, the wsdl file doesnt get generate. But when I keep the return type as String, it works fine. 
What is the issue here? How can I return a custom object.

```
@WebService
public interface Transaction {

    @WebMethod(action="createPurchase", operationName = "purchase")
    ResultDto purchase(String partyId, String dealId); --> This does not work
    String purchase(String partyId, String dealId);  --> This works 

}
```

### ResultDto

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name = "ResultDto")

 public class ResultDto {

 public String status;

 public String errorMessage;
 public int errorCode;

 // Getterrs and setters 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put @WebResult(name="ResultDto") before your method

```
@WebService
public interface Transaction {
    @WebMethod(action="createPurchase", operationName = "purchase")
    @WebResult(name="ResultDto")
    ResultDto purchase(String partyId, String dealId); 
 }
```